Connected to WiFi but there is no internet
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Pop
Description:    Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

I was able to connect to the Internet until Sunday. I couldn't connect to the Internet on Monday. Nothing has changed on my PC. The only thing I did was sudo apt-get update but it didn't download too much. As far as I can remember, it only downloaded a few kb of data.
In the house, all the phones are able to connect to the internet via WiFi, except my laptop. When I select the WiFi, it looks connected at first, but then a question mark (?) appears on the WiFi icon. Additionally, when I share my mobile internet with my laptop, everything works fine.
The strangest thing is I can connect to the Internet in another house too.
$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp47s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d8:bb:c1:b1:1d:c1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c4:bd:e5:23:9c:9a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname wlp0s20f3
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:aa:aa:8b:28 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: br-a593dce43362: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:84:e4:1e:5d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: br-c77e5c8b1ce6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:dd:ac:10:97 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: br-c8d5ce7ce6c1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:23:b0:8b:d6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: br-f2e659a6d01a: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:42:33:b3:08 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
9: br-fd59d8ed402b: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:0a:00:a2:96 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
10: br-35b3c8def3c9: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:be:6f:12:8f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
11: br-3a165a5c993a: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:eb:5e:ba:28 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
12: br-4d363be4b599: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:32:57:dd:21 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
13: br-4e168a0cdf31: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:81:00:13:f0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
14: br-9346c9dd9a25: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:43:b1:ee:3b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
15: br-a28feae6b83c: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:5d:ba:38:c8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
16: br-1db02a26bdd0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:e4:ff:fe:a0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
17: br-4ca8610e3d72: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:c7:ee:50:8c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
18: br-604867f1852d: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:db:85:46:ce brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
19: br-8166f1f24274: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:90:63:2e:3f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
20: br-3864e73fa63c: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:fa:fe:ab:c1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
21: br-46e81cf5fb5e: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:2e:dd:b3:a5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
22: br-dafd9fc1c73f: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:d8:d7:e3:9d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

$ ip -br addr
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8 ::1/128 
enp47s0          DOWN           
wlo1             UP             192.168.0.13/24 fe80::7820:93db:b655:d21f/64 
docker0          DOWN           172.17.0.1/16 
br-a593dce43362  DOWN           172.18.0.1/16 
br-c77e5c8b1ce6  DOWN           192.168.16.1/20 
br-c8d5ce7ce6c1  DOWN           172.29.0.1/16 
br-f2e659a6d01a  DOWN           172.20.0.1/16 
br-fd59d8ed402b  DOWN           172.28.0.1/16 
br-35b3c8def3c9  DOWN           172.30.0.1/16 
br-3a165a5c993a  DOWN           172.25.0.1/16 
br-4d363be4b599  DOWN           172.19.0.1/16 
br-4e168a0cdf31  DOWN           172.27.0.1/16 
br-9346c9dd9a25  DOWN           172.26.0.1/16 
br-a28feae6b83c  DOWN           172.21.0.1/16 
br-1db02a26bdd0  DOWN           172.31.0.1/16 
br-4ca8610e3d72  DOWN           192.168.0.1/20 
br-604867f1852d  DOWN           172.22.0.1/16 
br-8166f1f24274  DOWN           172.24.0.1/16 
br-3864e73fa63c  DOWN           192.168.49.1/24 
br-46e81cf5fb5e  DOWN           192.168.240.1/20 
br-dafd9fc1c73f  DOWN           172.23.0.1/16 

$ ip route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlo1 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlo1 scope link metric 1000 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-a593dce43362 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 linkdown 
172.19.0.0/16 dev br-4d363be4b599 proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.1 linkdown 
172.20.0.0/16 dev br-f2e659a6d01a proto kernel scope link src 172.20.0.1 linkdown 
172.21.0.0/16 dev br-a28feae6b83c proto kernel scope link src 172.21.0.1 linkdown 
172.22.0.0/16 dev br-604867f1852d proto kernel scope link src 172.22.0.1 linkdown 
172.23.0.0/16 dev br-dafd9fc1c73f proto kernel scope link src 172.23.0.1 linkdown 
172.24.0.0/16 dev br-8166f1f24274 proto kernel scope link src 172.24.0.1 linkdown 
172.25.0.0/16 dev br-3a165a5c993a proto kernel scope link src 172.25.0.1 linkdown 
172.26.0.0/16 dev br-9346c9dd9a25 proto kernel scope link src 172.26.0.1 linkdown 
172.27.0.0/16 dev br-4e168a0cdf31 proto kernel scope link src 172.27.0.1 linkdown 
172.28.0.0/16 dev br-fd59d8ed402b proto kernel scope link src 172.28.0.1 linkdown 
172.29.0.0/16 dev br-c8d5ce7ce6c1 proto kernel scope link src 172.29.0.1 linkdown 
172.30.0.0/16 dev br-35b3c8def3c9 proto kernel scope link src 172.30.0.1 linkdown 
172.31.0.0/16 dev br-1db02a26bdd0 proto kernel scope link src 172.31.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlo1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.13 metric 600 
192.168.0.0/20 dev br-4ca8610e3d72 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.16.0/20 dev br-c77e5c8b1ce6 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.16.1 linkdown 
192.168.49.0/24 dev br-3864e73fa63c proto kernel scope link src 192.168.49.1 linkdown 
192.168.240.0/20 dev br-46e81cf5fb5e proto kernel scope link src 192.168.240.1 linkdown

$ ip neigh
192.168.0.11 dev wlo1 lladdr 42:3f:8c:00:d9:f7 STALE
192.168.0.1 dev wlo1 lladdr e4:26:86:aa:d8:44 REACHABLE

$ sudo iptables-save -c
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Tue Apr 16 20:35:55 2024
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [3:673]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
[3:673] -A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
[3:673] -A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o br-dafd9fc1c73f -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o br-dafd9fc1c73f -j DOCKER
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i br-dafd9fc1c73f ! -o br-dafd9fc1c73f -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i br-dafd9fc1c73f -o br-dafd9fc1c73f -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o br-46e81cf5fb5e -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o br-46e81cf5fb5e -j DOCKER
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i br-46e81cf5fb5e ! -o br-46e81cf5fb5e -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i br-46e81cf5fb5e -o br-46e81cf5fb5e -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o br-3864e73fa63c -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o br-3864e73fa63c -j DOCKER
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i br-3864e73fa63c ! -o br-3864e73fa63c -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i br-3864e73fa63c -o br-3864e73fa63c -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o br-8166f1f24274 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o br-8166f1f24274 -j DOCKER
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i br-8166f1f24274 ! -o br-8166f1f24274 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i br-8166f1f24274 -o br-8166f1f24274 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o br-604867f1852d -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o br-604867f1852d -j DOCKER
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i br-604867f1852d ! -o br-604867f1852d -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i br-604867f1852d -o br-604867f1852d -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o br-4ca8610e3d72 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o br-4ca8610e3d72 -j DOCKER
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i br-4ca8610e3d72 ! -o br-4ca8610e3d72 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i br-4ca8610e3d72 -o br-4ca8610e3d72 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o br-1db02a26bdd0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o br-1db02a26bdd0 -j DOCKER
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i br-1db02a26bdd0 ! -o br-1db02a26bdd0 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i br-1db02a26bdd0 -o br-1db02a26bdd0 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o br-a28feae6b83c -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o br-a28feae6b83c -j DOCKER
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i br-a28feae6b83c ! -o br-a28feae6b83c -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i br-a28feae6b83c -o br-a28feae6b83c -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o br-9346c9dd9a25 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o br-9346c9dd9a25 -j DOCKER
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i br-9346c9dd9a25 ! -o br-9346c9dd9a25 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i br-9346c9dd9a25 -o br-9346c9dd9a25 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o br-4e168a0cdf31 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o br-4e168a0cdf31 -j DOCKER
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i br-4e168a0cdf31 ! -o br-4e168a0cdf31 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i br-4e168a0cdf31 -o br-4e168a0cdf31 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o br-4d363be4b599 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o br-4d363be4b599 -j DOCKER
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i br-4d363be4b599 ! -o br-4d363be4b599 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i br-4d363be4b599 -o br-4d363be4b599 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o br-3a165a5c993a -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o br-3a165a5c993a -j DOCKER
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i br-3a165a5c993a ! -o br-3a165a5c993a -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i br-3a165a5c993a -o br-3a165a5c993a -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o br-35b3c8def3c9 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o br-35b3c8def3c9 -j DOCKER
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i br-35b3c8def3c9 ! -o br-35b3c8def3c9 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i br-35b3c8def3c9 -o br-35b3c8def3c9 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o br-fd59d8ed402b -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o br-fd59d8ed402b -j DOCKER
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i br-fd59d8ed402b ! -o br-fd59d8ed402b -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i br-fd59d8ed402b -o br-fd59d8ed402b -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o br-f2e659a6d01a -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o br-f2e659a6d01a -j DOCKER
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i br-f2e659a6d01a ! -o br-f2e659a6d01a -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i br-f2e659a6d01a -o br-f2e659a6d01a -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o br-c8d5ce7ce6c1 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o br-c8d5ce7ce6c1 -j DOCKER
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i br-c8d5ce7ce6c1 ! -o br-c8d5ce7ce6c1 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i br-c8d5ce7ce6c1 -o br-c8d5ce7ce6c1 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o br-c77e5c8b1ce6 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o br-c77e5c8b1ce6 -j DOCKER
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i br-c77e5c8b1ce6 ! -o br-c77e5c8b1ce6 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i br-c77e5c8b1ce6 -o br-c77e5c8b1ce6 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o br-a593dce43362 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o br-a593dce43362 -j DOCKER
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i br-a593dce43362 ! -o br-a593dce43362 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i br-a593dce43362 -o br-a593dce43362 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-dafd9fc1c73f ! -o br-dafd9fc1c73f -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-46e81cf5fb5e ! -o br-46e81cf5fb5e -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-3864e73fa63c ! -o br-3864e73fa63c -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-8166f1f24274 ! -o br-8166f1f24274 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-604867f1852d ! -o br-604867f1852d -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-4ca8610e3d72 ! -o br-4ca8610e3d72 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-1db02a26bdd0 ! -o br-1db02a26bdd0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-a28feae6b83c ! -o br-a28feae6b83c -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-9346c9dd9a25 ! -o br-9346c9dd9a25 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-4e168a0cdf31 ! -o br-4e168a0cdf31 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-4d363be4b599 ! -o br-4d363be4b599 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-3a165a5c993a ! -o br-3a165a5c993a -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-35b3c8def3c9 ! -o br-35b3c8def3c9 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-fd59d8ed402b ! -o br-fd59d8ed402b -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-f2e659a6d01a ! -o br-f2e659a6d01a -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-c8d5ce7ce6c1 ! -o br-c8d5ce7ce6c1 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-c77e5c8b1ce6 ! -o br-c77e5c8b1ce6 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-a593dce43362 ! -o br-a593dce43362 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
[3:673] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-dafd9fc1c73f -j DROP
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-46e81cf5fb5e -j DROP
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-3864e73fa63c -j DROP
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-8166f1f24274 -j DROP
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-604867f1852d -j DROP
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-4ca8610e3d72 -j DROP
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-1db02a26bdd0 -j DROP
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-a28feae6b83c -j DROP
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-9346c9dd9a25 -j DROP
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-4e168a0cdf31 -j DROP
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-4d363be4b599 -j DROP
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-3a165a5c993a -j DROP
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-35b3c8def3c9 -j DROP
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-fd59d8ed402b -j DROP
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-f2e659a6d01a -j DROP
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-c8d5ce7ce6c1 -j DROP
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-c77e5c8b1ce6 -j DROP
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-a593dce43362 -j DROP
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
[3:673] -A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Apr 16 20:35:55 2024
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Tue Apr 16 20:35:55 2024
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
[3:1090] -A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
[778:52788] -A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 172.23.0.0/16 ! -o br-dafd9fc1c73f -j MASQUERADE
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.240.0/20 ! -o br-46e81cf5fb5e -j MASQUERADE
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.49.0/24 ! -o br-3864e73fa63c -j MASQUERADE
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 172.24.0.0/16 ! -o br-8166f1f24274 -j MASQUERADE
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 172.22.0.0/16 ! -o br-604867f1852d -j MASQUERADE
[2202:192320] -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/20 ! -o br-4ca8610e3d72 -j MASQUERADE
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 172.31.0.0/16 ! -o br-1db02a26bdd0 -j MASQUERADE
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 172.21.0.0/16 ! -o br-a28feae6b83c -j MASQUERADE
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 172.26.0.0/16 ! -o br-9346c9dd9a25 -j MASQUERADE
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 172.27.0.0/16 ! -o br-4e168a0cdf31 -j MASQUERADE
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 172.19.0.0/16 ! -o br-4d363be4b599 -j MASQUERADE
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 172.25.0.0/16 ! -o br-3a165a5c993a -j MASQUERADE
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 172.30.0.0/16 ! -o br-35b3c8def3c9 -j MASQUERADE
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 172.28.0.0/16 ! -o br-fd59d8ed402b -j MASQUERADE
[631:65752] -A POSTROUTING -s 172.20.0.0/16 ! -o br-f2e659a6d01a -j MASQUERADE
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 172.29.0.0/16 ! -o br-c8d5ce7ce6c1 -j MASQUERADE
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.16.0/20 ! -o br-c77e5c8b1ce6 -j MASQUERADE
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 172.18.0.0/16 ! -o br-a593dce43362 -j MASQUERADE
[0:0] -A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
[0:0] -A DOCKER -i br-dafd9fc1c73f -j RETURN
[0:0] -A DOCKER -i br-46e81cf5fb5e -j RETURN
[0:0] -A DOCKER -i br-3864e73fa63c -j RETURN
[0:0] -A DOCKER -i br-8166f1f24274 -j RETURN
[0:0] -A DOCKER -i br-604867f1852d -j RETURN
[0:0] -A DOCKER -i br-4ca8610e3d72 -j RETURN
[0:0] -A DOCKER -i br-1db02a26bdd0 -j RETURN
[0:0] -A DOCKER -i br-a28feae6b83c -j RETURN
[0:0] -A DOCKER -i br-9346c9dd9a25 -j RETURN
[0:0] -A DOCKER -i br-4e168a0cdf31 -j RETURN
[0:0] -A DOCKER -i br-4d363be4b599 -j RETURN
[0:0] -A DOCKER -i br-3a165a5c993a -j RETURN
[0:0] -A DOCKER -i br-35b3c8def3c9 -j RETURN
[0:0] -A DOCKER -i br-fd59d8ed402b -j RETURN
[0:0] -A DOCKER -i br-f2e659a6d01a -j RETURN
[0:0] -A DOCKER -i br-c8d5ce7ce6c1 -j RETURN
[0:0] -A DOCKER -i br-c77e5c8b1ce6 -j RETURN
[0:0] -A DOCKER -i br-a593dce43362 -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Apr 16 20:35:55 2024


Can you run this on the laptop once the Wifi is connected and you attempt to use Internet? ip link; ip -br addr; ip route; ip neigh and (as root or with sudo) iptables-save -c. Can you edit the question and add the output from these commands (as text)?

@A.B changes have done. Could you revise, please?

TL;DR: blame Docker.

Your Wifi gateway has IP address 192.168.0.1/24.
One of your numerous Docker networks uses 192.168.0.0/20, with a local host IP address of 192.168.0.1/20: the same as the gateway (even if the netmask is different).
This creates routing conflicts when trying to reach the gateway for the default route to Internet: 192.168.0.1 is a local address.
I guess this might turn the whole Internet into a LAN (because using oneself as gateway is the same as having no gateway): some requests to Internet IP address will trigger an ARP request instead of using the gateway.
The quick (but temporary) fix: stop Docker and remove the conflicting bridge interface:
sudo systemctl stop docker docker.socket
sudo ip link del dev br-4ca8610e3d72

The actual fix is to remove all Docker networks (using docker network prune or docker network rm ...) and change Docker's configuration so it won't use the conflicting networks. Check for example this serverfault Q/A:
Configuring Docker to not use the 172.17.0.0 range
(and use something in the 10. ... ranges)
You might also want to do regular cleanup of unused Docker resources, usually involving docker ... prune ..., so there is no such accumulation of Docker networks.

Can you explain how did you detect that, please?

Habit? I consider Docker is to blame for most network issues when it's installed. Once I saw Docker was involved, I searched how it would cause a problem until I found this conflict (didn't take much time to find 192.168.0.1 existing twice).

Thank you so much for details
